# prove that $‎‎P(X=0) \leq ‎\frac{Var(X)}{‎‎‎E(X‎^{2})‎}‎$.

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X$ be a random variable taking integral nonnegative values, let $E [X^2]$
denote the expectation of its square, and let $Var [X]$ denote its variance. Prove
that $‎‎P(X=0) \leq ‎\frac{Var(X)}{‎‎‎E(X‎^{2})‎}‎$‎.

I try to use this theorem which will be proved by Chebyshev's Inequality:$‎‎P(X=0) \leq ‎\frac{Var(X)}{‎‎‎E(X‎)^{2}‎}$, I try to prove this $E(X‎^{2}) \geq E(X‎)^{2} $ and using above inequality it will be done. but I couldn't prove this,I thought that using the definition of expectation will help but I am not sure,please help me with some guidance or hint or any reference,thank you very much.

Comment: The bound $\operatorname{E}[X^2] \ge \operatorname{E}[X]^2$ is not enough to prove the desired bound.

Note that the bound obtained via Chebyshev, $\operatorname{Pr}[X = 0] \leq \operatorname{Var}[X]/\operatorname{E}[X]^2$, is weaker than the one you want to prove (as $\operatorname{Var}[X]/\operatorname{E}[X^2] \leq \operatorname{Var}[X]/\operatorname{E}[X]^2$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\text{Var}[X] \geq 0$ (this is a well-known fact), $E[X^2] - (E[X])^2 \geq 0$ and the inequality desired follows.

Comment: thank you very much,it was my big mistake to not pay attention well.

Comment: As shown by @David Hackenger the inequality does not follow immediately from the inequality provided by the OP. So how did you derive it?