# Understanding proof that $P(X=0) \leq \frac{Var(X)}{E(X^2)}$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, variance

I want to understand how to show that for a random variable X which takes non-negative values, it holds that
$$P(X=0) \leq \frac{\textrm{Var}(X)}{E(X^2)}$$

There already is a solution to that question, but I can't see why the inequality immediately follows when I know that $\textrm{Var}(X) \geq 0$

[prove that $‎‎P(X=0) \leq ‎\frac{Var(X)}{‎‎‎E(X‎^{2})‎}‎$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/767639/prove-that-px-0-leq-fracvarxex2)

Comment: I wouldn't pay too much attention to the linked question. In that question the OP says "If I could only prove that $E(X^2)\ge E(X)^2$, I could finish the proof using Chebyshev's inequality". To which the answerer says "Don't you see, $0\le \operatorname{Var}(X)=E(X^2)-E(X)^2$ so your statement $E(X^2)\ge E(X)^2$ follows immediately". However, a commenter says "Even if you prove what you want, you cannot follow up with Chebyshev's inequality to complete the proof, it will give you a weaker result!"...

Comment: You are right, I just realised that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remark that $\mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}[X1_{X>0}]$ and apply Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
$$\mathbb{E}[X]^2\leq \mathbb{E}[X^2]\mathbb{E}[1_{X>0}] = \mathbb{E}[X^2](1-\mathbb{P}(X=0)). $$
Then conclude
$$\mathbb{P}(X=0) \leq 1 - \frac{\mathbb{E}[X]^2}{\mathbb{E}[X^2]} = \frac{\text{Var} X}{\mathbb{E}[X^2]}. $$